# I can't add numbers together using JavaScript, why?

Tags: javascript, addition

I am a beginner at JavaScript and am currently trying to create a very basic webbsite for throwing dice. For some reason I can't add two numbers together correctly. The following code is supposed to add the value of each dice, but doesn't. Could someone please explain why, and how to fix it?

```
        let numRolls = document.getElementById('numhitrolls').value;
        let modifier = document.getElementById('tohit-modifier').value;
        

        if(document.getElementById('neither').checked == true){
            for( let i = 0; i < numRolls; i++){
                roll = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1);
                roll += modifier;
                alert(roll);
                }
```

For some reason I get a message with a number that is way to high. I want to add the value of the modifier and the roll, but instead I'm getting a value such as '1112' (modifier = 12), and I can't understand why.
Help is much appreciated

Comment: `Element.value` will always return a **string**. It's your job as a developer to convert `value` to the needed, float, integer, number etc. Open console and type `11 + "12"` what to you see? Exactly, `"1112"` instead of `23`. Therefore, use `roll += +modifier;` or `roll += Number(modifier);`

Comment: give me full code html ans js

Comment: FYI if the inputs are `type="number"` you can use [valueAsNumber](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#valueasnumber)

Comment: @Philisonstrike Hey that's handy!  Thanks.